# Centering all facets on 0 in ggplot with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have what is hopefully a simple question.

I am using `facet_wrap()` to stack 3 plots on top of each other.

I am hoping to get all 3 plots centered at 0, so the `hline` all are directly above each other. Ideally while also allowing their scales to range freely as needed along the `x-axis` (which I am already doing with `scales = "free"`).

Any ideas? See the **example code and data** below.

```
d_example %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = var, y = coef, 
             ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper,
             color = race)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7),
             size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0, 
                size = 1.1, 
                alpha = 0.6, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  facet_wrap(~ outcome, 
             nrow = 3,
             scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             color = "black",
             size = .3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

```
d_example <- structure(list(var = c("score_A", "score_B", "score_C", "score_A", 
"score_B", "score_C", "score_A", "score_B", "score_C", "friends_A", 
"friends_B", "friends_A", "friends_B", "friends_A", "friends_B", 
"poverty_A", "poverty_B", "poverty_A", "poverty_B", "poverty_A", 
"poverty_B"), coef = c(-0.8, -0.7, 0.12, -0.7, -0.9, -0.05, -0.73, 
-1, 0.02, 0.55, -0.09, 0.51, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05, 1.8, 0.34, 1.103, 
0.077, 1.02, 0.06), race = c("white", "white", "white", "black", 
"black", "black", "hispanic", "hispanic", "hispanic", "white", 
"white", "black", "black", "hispanic", "hispanic", "white", "white", 
"black", "black", "hispanic", "hispanic"), outcome = c("score", 
"score", "score", "score", "score", "score", "score", "score", 
"score", "friends", "friends", "friends", "friends", "friends", 
"friends", "ses", "ses", "ses", "ses", "ses", "ses"), ci_lower = c(-1, 
-0.9, -0.08, -0.9, -1.1, -0.25, -0.93, -1.2, -0.18, 0.35, -0.29, 
0.31, 0, 0.45, -0.15, 1.6, 0.14, 0.903, -0.123, 0.82, -0.14), 
    ci_upper = c(-0.6, -0.5, 0.32, -0.5, -0.7, 0.15, -0.53, -0.8, 
    0.22, 0.75, 0.11, 0.71, 0.4, 0.85, 0.25, 2, 0.54, 1.303, 
    0.277, 1.22, 0.26)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), coef = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), outcome = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ci_lower = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ci_upper = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: How do you want your conditions (especially the "range freely" + align zero parts) to be met? 1) give every plot the same x range. 2) give every plot a range from -n to n, such that 0 is in the middle, 3) give every plot a range from -an to n, such that 0 is not in the middle but the same place on each chart 4) give every plot the range it has now, but shift the positioning of the plot itself so that the zeros align, 5) something else?

Comment: I think 2 or 3, with a preference for 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hacky but simple answer that gives each facet a free range, while keeping zero in the center:

Add an invisible layer with reversed y's, such that every facet will be naturally symmetrical around 0.

```
geom_errorbar(aes(y = -coef, ymin = -ci_lower, ymax = -ci_upper),
              alpha = 0,
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
```

Or, better, you could use @r2evans' suggestion of `geom_blank`, which was specifically designed for situations where you want your plot to make room for certain data points, without wasting cycles or bytes actually drawing them. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_blank.html

```
 geom_blank(aes(y = -coef, ymin = -ci_lower, ymax = -ci_upper)) +
```

[image]

Comment: Woah! This is cool. Had not thought of this at all. I like it, thanks.

Comment: +1 since I like the trick. -1 since I feel the distortion is misrepresenting the magnitude and uncertainty in the data. I guess it's a wash? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Interestingly, you can do this same thing with `geom_blank(aes(y = -ci_lower)) + geom_blank(aes(y = -ci_upper))` without the invisible dots. (I know low-alpha dots actually take time to render, do 0-alpha dots slow down rendering at all? I've done some 100k+ low-alpha PDFs before that were not nice to the processor ...)

Comment: Thanks for the `geom_blank()` tip, that is better. As for the distortion, I agree that for most use cases with common variables you'd want a common scale. But I could also imagine legitimate cases where one might not value comparability between facets. Perhaps "coef" is not on the same scale between facets... Perhaps we care more about the coefficient of variation, ie the width of the error bars compared to the scale of the numbers... Perhaps the coefficients vary by orders of magnitude but we want to represent them as precisely as the available space allows...

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding `scale_y_continuous(limits=)` below; this allows easy alignment of the hlines:

```r
d_example %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var, y = coef,
             ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper,
             color = race)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7),
             size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0,
                size = 1.1,
                alpha = 0.6,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  facet_wrap(~ outcome,
             nrow = 3,
             scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             linetype = "dashed",
             color = "black",
             linewidth = .3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = range(unlist(d_example[,c("coef","ci_lower","ci_upper")]))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

If you want truly-centered, use this instead:

```r
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,1) * max(abs(range(unlist(d_example[,c("coef","ci_lower","ci_upper")])))))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is along the lines of what I first attempted. However, my hope is to still allow the x axes to be free the same as they would if I didn't try to align the 0s. This solution imposes the same x axis range on each facet.

Comment: You say you want the 0s to align but without constraining the x-axis. If you somehow get them to align but not by imposing the same limits, then while 0 might align the _magnitudes_ in each direction will not. While that will technically resolve your request, it will also make a plot that "lies" by misrepresenting (visually) the relative comparison of error bars. I suggest you take a moment to draw what you think an aligned by unconstrained plot looks like given this data; perhaps on a whiteboard or piece of paper; it would help me understand other options for this.

Comment: Visually, I think what @Jon Spring produced is basically exactly what I had in mind. I'm not sure how that plot "lies" or misrepresents anything, the error bars don't seem skewed to me. But perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: If you look at JonSpring's graphic, an easy intuition to glean from it is that lines of the same visual width have the same "error" scale to them, and if two bars are equally distant from the center, they have the same magnitude. The axis ticks/labels try to mitigate this, but the distortion is already done. For instance, looking at the bottom orange line in "friends" and the bottom orange line in "ses", in JonSpring's graphic they look like very different widths but near the same location, when in fact the latter is twice the value and the same width. Distortion easily mis-represents data.